# My Javascript doesn't seems work (partially)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to give my welcome texts some animations using delay and show. When i test it locally, everything works fine. However, when I try to run it on live server, the codes in "first load on delay" and "jquery for front page" is not working at all, WHILE the codes in "responsive manipulator" section works???
If the whole script doesn't work then I might figured out something, but strangely some of it is working.

Can anyone tell me what's happening?

Here is the HTML

```
<div ng-controller="homeController" class="ng-scope">
<div class="flex-box welcome">
    <h1 id="line1" class="hvr-pulse">Welcome to my basement</h1>
    <h3 id="line2" class="hvr-pulse">I hope these will satisfy you</h3>
    <button id="welcome-button" class="hvr-grow-rotate" ng-click="about()">Allow me to introduce myself</button>
</div>
```

Hear my greeting -->

Here is the Javascripts file, and the site url is https://namwin.herokuapp.com/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // first load on delay
    $('#line1').hide().delay(3000).show(2200);
    $('#line2').hide().delay(5000).show(2200);
    $('#welcome-button').hide().delay(10000).show(2200);

    //responsive manipulator
    $('.fa-bars').on('click',function () {
        var x = document.getElementById("nav-bar");
        if (x.className === 'nav-bar')
            x.className += ' responsive';
        else
            x.className = 'nav-bar';
    })

    // jquery for front page
    $('#greet').click(function() {
        var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
        if (audio.paused) {
            audio.play();
        }else{
            audio.pause();
            audio.currentTime = 0
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Can you also include your HTML related to the question?

Comment: those elements might not be in DOM. Can you add some complete picture of your HTML?

Comment: `delay()` != `setTimeout()`  The two methods are completely different and, as the API explicitly states, delay is not a replacement for setTimeout

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve, but as a sidenote, jQuery provides the methods `hasClass()`, `addClass()` and `removeClass()`, so your `if` statement should be something like `if (x.hasClass('responsive')) { x.removeClass('responsive') } else { x.addClass('responsive') }`. Also note that [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) has the optional parameters `duration` and a `complete` callback, which you can use to chain methods. Anyway, your animations are working for me on Safari.

Comment: I just added the HTML. My bad, it is delay() not setTimeout. And for Alejandro question, I am trying to give my element #line1, #line2, #welcome-text to have some delay before showing it when user first load the page. Right now they have no delay (even though on local the delay functions work...) I am using Chrome by the way, maybe that's the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using angular place this code in your module.
You are calling the code, while the elements arent there yet.